# Import Access database table design properties but not data

Tags: database, ms-access

I've got a large amount of access databases that need to have the same table design changes (and a few new tables created) in each of them. Is there any way to take my most recent (properly designed) database, export the design properties, and import them to each of the other databases overwriting changes and creating any new fields, tables, etc. as needed?

My research has only led me to the Database documenter which seems to only be helpful in cases where I'd manually update the properties. I also know I could potentially copy each table over manually specifying 'Structure Only' for each case but that'd be a rather daunting task and I'm unsure what exactly would be copied using this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a utility called [DBWeigher](http://dbweigher.com/) which is able to analyze and compare two access databases and automatically generate the necessary VBcode to update the changes between the two. From here I quickly ran through the changes manually and was able to see firsthand what changes would be made prior to running them through the DBConsole.

For anyone trying to update older access databases (especially when they're at different stages and could have some variances), I can't suggest checking this lightweight utility out.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I have the outline...

```
Open  Proper.mdb

For each OtherMDB in Folder1
    Open OtherMDB
    for each ProperTable in Proper.mdb
        If ProperTable is absent from OtherMDB
             Add ProperTable to OtherMDB
        Else
            For each Field in ProperTable.Fields
                 If ProperField is absent from OtherTable.Fields
                      Add Field to OtherTable
                 Elseif  ' is this a possibility?? wanting to change field type?
                     ProperField.Type <> OtherTable.Field("xx").Type Then
                         Change Field.Type
                 endif
             Next Field
         Endif
     Next Table
     Close OtherMDB
Next MDB
```

Comment: You just about have it I believe. My concern is making sure I'm copying/overwriting ALL properties within each table(i.e. looping through to ensure required, char limits, etc. are copied). I wasn't sure if Access had a built in feature similar to just importing just the database structure in which case I don't mind doing a tiny bit of manual labor as there are ~20 mdb's only. Using the import would result in a large amount of duplicated tables as it doesn't offer to overwrite just the structure unfortunately. I appreciate your help and hope you may be able to further direct/assist me.

Comment: Just a few overview items-- 1)Are all the OtherMDB-s in one folder or many? how are they identified and selected?  2)It would be simpler if there were not changes to Field.Type... is this a requirement?  3)what version of MSAccess are you running?  4)What part of the above have you started to write? 5)what problem is outstanding?  6)Can you post the ProperMDB and one sample OtherMDB without exposing confidential data? maybe delete all the data and leave the structures? tkx

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back. I really appreciate your assistance in starting the base framework for the code but I'm about to post an answer with a utility I found that was able to achieve exactly what I wanted.